# Vue method scope, return from if statement not returning

Tags: if-statement, vue.js, methods, scope, return

I want to return true/false from a Vue method depending on user role check inside v-for and the method is not returning from if statement.

First, template is like this (simplified)

```
<div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
 <div :contenteditable="checkuser(user)">{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

I just need true/false and this is the checkMethod

This doesn't work

```
    checkUser(user) {
      if (user.admin) {
        return user.team_id === this.$store.state.user.team_id;

       // I would expect to return from method here and not continue execution
       // also, any variables (even declared outside if) are not modified    

     }

      if (user.deleg) {
        return user.subteam_id === this.$store.state.user.subteam_id;
      }

      // method ends here
    }
```

I know this is stupid and simple but I cant get it working. If there is only one check it works ok obviously but I want to check it for 2 roles. Admin has also deleg permission so if user is admin it doesnt need to check for deleg, but if he doesnt have admin it should check for deleg.

Comment: Why do you have a prop called `contenteditable` on the inner div? div's can't use props anyways.

Comment: Execution will not continue beyond the `return`. If you think that's what's happening then you are misinterpreting something. I suggest putting a `debugger` statement at the beginning of the method so you can step through. It will be called once for each user, so perhaps the confusion comes from different invocations going down different paths.

Comment: @JacobSmith It isn't a prop, it's a standard HTML attribute.

Comment: @skirtle Standard HTML attributes are not prepended with `:`

Comment: `:` is just a shortcut for `v-bind:`, meaning that the value of the attribute is determined by a JS expression. There's no other rules beyond that

Answer (score 0):

**@skirtle, thank you**, you just did something to my brain with the confusion of invocations. It was entirely my thinking fail.

**Solved code below**

```
checkUser(user) {
      if (this.$store.getters.isAdmin) {
        return true;
      }

      if (this.$store.getters.isDeleg) {
        return user.subteam_id === this.$store.state.user.subteam_id;
      }
    }
```

**Explanation**

I was checking for the passed **user.admin** from **v-for**, but I needed to check for **user.admin** of **currently logged** in user (if he can edit the content, then bind that attribute to true/false). As I have this already in vuex I just grabbed it with getter and returned true (working as you said).

I hope it makes sense. Thanks once again, I was stuck and you helped me.

@Jacob, I am just binding contenteditable to true/false with this function.